# What are the steps for installing UML Designer in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, uml-designer

I am having no success at installing UML Designer in Eclipse for Java Developers.

I have tried 6 different versions of the Eclipse IDE, going back as far as 2020-09. I have also tried installing Sirius first, but that also resulted in errors during installation. Finally, I have tried both the Eclipse Marketplace route and the "Install new software" route using the software repository URLs. Lastly, I have combed the internet looking for a "how-to", or similar, without any luck.

I assume, given that this discussion category is ongoing, that it is possible to install UML Designer in some version of Eclipse. :-) Can somebody please walk me through the exact steps that were followed to achieve a successful install?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: It looks pretty straightforward: see https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/uml-designer/help.  If you are getting errors, you should tell us specifically what they are ... so that someone can figure out what is going wrong for you.   Alternatively, trawl through the existing SO questions on this topic, looking for symptoms that match the symptoms that you are seeing.  Google for `install uml designer in eclipse errors site:stackoverflow.com`.

Comment: But if you are simply asking for a reference to a "walk through" document, that is off-topic.

Comment: Finally, I found this in the Marketplace comments: *"In order to improve the tool could you report what is missing for you and what does not work as you expect on our bug tracker: `https://github.com/ObeoNetwork/UML-Designer/issues`
Do not hesitate to contact us to get some support: `http://www.umldesigner.org/support/`
Thanks for your feedback!"*